# Scrapy cannot scrape data

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]I am trying to scrape data from real estate site https://www.spitogatos.gr/.
I saw from robots.txt there is that: The Ultimate robots.txt Bot and User-Agent Blocker
I just want to scrape the site every day one time, it's a way around to scrape using scrapy?
thank you in advance

```
import scrapy
    class MainprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mainProject'
    allowed_domains = ['www.spitogatos.gr']
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
    Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
   #start_urls = ['https://www.spitogatos.gr/']
   
     def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.spitogatos.gr', callback = self.parse,
        headers= {'User Agent':self.user_agent})        
     def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//h2[@class="text thin h1"]/text()').extract())#just dummy
     def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request
```

Comment: Does it have to be in scrapy or could you use urllib and requests to download page and then maybe use beautiful soup to parse it?

Comment: I will try it with beautiful soup and download it, but I just want it with scrapy as a challenge is my personal "pet project" so if I could scrape it with scrapy It would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing only User-Agent in headers is not sufficient to get successful response. You have to pass the complete request header and cookies for this website.

**Code**

```
import scrapy

class MainprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mainProject'
    allowed_domains = ['spitogatos.gr']

    headers = {
        "authority": "www.spitogatos.gr",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

    cookies = {
        "PHPSESSID": "po638herud8fh5bcd5faj6e2fn",
        "spitogatosHomepageMap": "0",
        "currentCurrency": "EUR",
        "_ga": "GA1.2.995321575.1625941672",
        "_gid": "GA1.2.2083505143.1625941672",
        "_hjTLDTest": "1",
        "_hjid": "81d5a4f5-1d68-4f26-86c9-be4f6f3c4072",
        "_fbp": "fb.1.1625941672273.1445941947",
        "__qca": "P0-96032413-1625941956393",
        "_hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress": "1",
        "openedTabs": "1",
        "_gat_UA-3455846-10": "1",
        "_gat_UA-3455846-2": "1",
        "_hjIncludedInSessionSample": "1",
        "reese84": "3:FGNSnDE4wRMItXmgo8P+Aw==:sGtH84yEJkKj63PngFcdU3iQbhkp11cYkDw3X06dMlyaUb7wTkc2Wah9Qovgk4eW/Gg34paBwJIFH5ywVR4iJmb+542uPLVNXHnd4LXLKtVOTdeLrew41lAeyvKyjAcHlsIW+El8j8715RwI9TirIOa50wILShhQbubz89vw4m4rSnNrNbI73GMNWQZBIaSG3Lct5PuBfdJjdl3rT4Fp1kR7dV/yggGv1e6T33RgojXdT23MRb9uG7TojFqiIlI75yqZ8XdxqsSDClwWq8b/vFbUagC19NlptsyY1OsG2v7jguFXIdcHeLnKTAx8UJ+cHz6heewN6SAGrdqw8b2GMVuvpbBhatIdmiP7d0+J5RUU+g5DO9eFGGiWV3ToR47VwCI48X4jxnhkslnXSnCesudsSh3mVIFWGRBIYL723SI=:K71/ib2SBQ6VfoGMhHDTkyPcg91uLZr+BqNFsVE0WFs="
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/'
        yield  scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            method='GET',
            cookies=self.cookies,
            headers=self.headers,
            callback= self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//h2[@class="text thin h1"]/text()').extract()) # your dummy xpath
```

Comment: how did you knew it, you have read it on the documentary?

Comment: You can use Postman tool, uncheck the header parameters one at a time & make subsequent request & then see if the complete response is generated. Continue this process for all the values. I hope you got it.

Comment: I used the postman extension very helpful. Just one question I tried to use postman app for the application, but on mupostman e.g. does not has "sec-fetch-site": "none", and others. How did you find this? from inspect network tab, and then cookies?

Comment: You have to make curl request through Postman and it will show all the parameters of request headers.

Comment: sorry for spamming, because I am newbie how I can export the curl from website using python?sorry for the stupid question.